# Find Root of a function generated by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

So I define a function

```
    fshoot[w_, f0_] := NDSolve[{-w^2 f[x] + Sin[f[x]] - 2 f'[x]/x - f''[x] ==0,
    f[xmin] == f0, f'[xmin] == 2 f2[w, f0] xmin + 4 f4[w, f0] xmin^3 + 6 f6[w, f0] xmin^5}, 
    f, {x, xmin, xmax}][[1]]
```

For each value of f0 and w I get a function f[x] as a solution. Now, I want to fix the value of f0 and find the value w which makes the function f[x] vanish at x=xmax, so I define

```
    froot[W_] := f[xmax]/.fshoot[W,f0];
```

Which is a function of W. Now I want to find the root of this function so I run

```
   FindRoot[froot[W], {W, .98}]
```

But the problem is that the NDSolve uses W as an unspecified number and so I don't get a numerical value for f[x] which then makes FindRoot unhappy because f[xmax] is not evaluated to a numeric value.

How can I modify my code so that it works?

Comment: what are`f2`, `f4` and `f6`? Without a minimal example that can be run, we cannot help you. Meanwhile, read `WhenEvent` information

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh). 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

## Quick fix

Quick fix can be achieved just by restricting `froot` function to take only numerical values:

```
froot[W_?NumericQ] := f[xmax] /. fshoot[W, f0];
```

## Proper way

However, your shooting algorithm better use `ParametricNDSolveValue` function, particularly, its feature to return the value at some point. An example from help (note the second parameter `f[10]`):

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''[t] + a f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, 
           f[10], {t, 0, 10}, {a}]

FindRoot[pfun[a], {a, 1}]
```

Your code:

```
fshoot[f0_] := ParametricNDSolveValue[{-w^2 f[x] + Sin[f[x]] - 2 f'[x]/x - f''[x] == 0,
           f[xmin] == f0,
           f'[xmin] == 2 f2[w, f0] xmin + 4 f4[w, f0] xmin^3 + 6 f6[w, f0] xmin^5},
           f[xmax], {x, xmin, xmax}, {w}];

froot = fshoot[f0];

FindRoot[froot[W], {W, .98}]
```